# Do smart-card readers support all smart-cards models?

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

Do smart-cards require a different kind of reader depending on the model or do all readers support all kinds of smart-cards? Assuming I have a specific card model in mind, how do I find out what kind of reader I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the chip used, have a look at:

- [Smart Card Readers and Terminals](http://www.scmmicro.com/products-services/smart-card-readers-terminals/smart-card-reader.html)
- [ISO/IEC 7816 Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7816)

Comment: Are you saying it depends on the chip manufacturer? Or on the interface type? Meaning, can I reasonably assume that all contact-chips support IEC 7816?

Comment: it depends on the type of chip used. e.g. certain chips have hardware security features added, which will not be used/read by standard readers. i am not really into the hardware stuff, but with a simple scm reader i was able to read sim cards, voucher cards, key cards, ec/maestro cards. of course you still need the crypt setup to access usefull data. what cards do you want to read out? or do you want to use an auth mechanism with your machine?

Comment: I want to use contact cards with public-key encryption that is PKCS #11 compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference with contact cards is synchronous memory cards vs asynchronous microprocessor cards.

Most "interesting" smart cards are asynchronous microprocessor cards (like SIM cards, bank cards, electronic ID badges etc).

Contact cards and contactless cards are a whole different story though.

Comment: So in theory, there are only two kinds of readers for contact smart-cards?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat surprised, to see a pointer-only answer as accepted, I supplement the following:

While there is a good chance, that a card and a reader will be able to communicate, watch out for these criteria:

- Maximum data field size; an important boundary is support of extended length APDUs (> 255 byte), required for 2048 bit RSA signatures
- For contact-based cards: external clock (3.57, 4.91, more than 5 MHz)and supported communication rates. Note that the default is just 9600 bit/s, so even reading a moderately sized file may become noticeable.
- Match of supported protocols between card and reader (T=0, T=1; T=CL)
- For contactless thoroughly check before; there are different frequency bands and incompatible protocols within the same frequency (ISO 14443 type A and type B)