# Does SLE4442 memory card returns ATR when it's connected?

Tags: smartcard

I have known that normal Smart Card (e.g. Java Card) returns ATR when it's connected to the reader.
But in this case, SLE4442 a memory card and use 2-wire protocol instead of T=0 or T=1.

Does it normally returns ATR?

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7151935/1435475) with some useful links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. If the reader is able to handle synchronous (i. e. memory) cards as the SLE4442 at all, it will synthesize an ATR however, since practically all applications require one to proceed.

The following communication will similarly be transformed by the reader, translating some READ BINARY command variant into the appropriate voltage levels and the reverse way for the answer.

The synthesized ATR is typically very short (5 to 6 bytes). For details look into the documentation of your reader.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is with Atmel 24C64 memory cards and two models of smart-card readers [Athena ASEDrive IIIe](https://en.cryptoshop.com/athena-asedrive-iiie-v2c-usb-reader-weiss.html) and [ACR38U](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/199/acr38u-i1-smart-card-reader/#features) (this one is noted to support your card)

They report an simple ATR:

`3B 00`

This fake ATR is constructed **by reader** itself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for all answers.

Recently, the ACS ACR39U reader that I bought have been arrived and I have tested it with the card. As both of the answers said, the reader synthesis ATR of the card by itself.

In my case, an ATR of SLE4442 memory card is `3B 04 AA BB CC DD`.

In summary, when SLE4442 memory card is connected to the reader, the reader returns an ATR that synthesized by the reader itself.